# Magento 2 - add a category attribute

Tags: magento, magento2, magento2.1

I'm tryng to create a custom category attribute using this [guide](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/ui_comp_guide/howto/add_category_attribute.html) but it doesn't work for me, this is the code that I'm using for the 
InstallData.php:

```
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
  private $eavSetupFactory;

  public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory) {
    $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
  }

  public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
  {
    $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
    $eavSetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY, 'disposizione', [
        'type'     => 'int',
        'label'    => 'Disposizione',
        'input'    => 'boolean',
        'source'   => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Boolean',
        'visible'  => true,
        'default'  => '0',
        'required' => false,
        'global'   => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
        'group'    => 'Display Settings',
    ]);
  }
}
```

category_form.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
<fieldset name="display_settings">
    <field name="disposizione">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">boolean</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">checkbox</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Nome Produttore</item>
                <item name="prefer" xsi:type="string">toggle</item>
                <item name="valueMap" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="true" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                    <item name="false" xsi:type="string">0</item>
                </item>
                <item name="default" xsi:type="number">0</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
  <module name="Ng_AddAttribute" setup_version="1.0.0" />
</config>
```

registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
  \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
  'Ng_AddAttribute',
  __DIR__
);
```

[image: Schermata_2018-08-07_alle_18.48.29.png]

After that i upgrade the schema with `bin/magento setup:upgrade` and clear the cache, but nothing happens, neither a error.
this is only a try, I need to create two attribute one text and one select.
could someone help me

Comment: Did you check in `eav_attribute` table a row with `attribute_id` = disposizione exist? If No that means your install script won't running. Add whole module code here to analyze what is going wrong.

Comment: in the `eav_attribute` table there is no new lines. here's the code of module.xml
`<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Ng_AddAttribute" setup_version="1.0.0" />
</config>`

Comment: Hey, all module files of Ng_AddAttribute I meant

Comment: i've edited the original post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Namespace is missing in your InstallData.php file. Replace file content with below code or just add namespace.

```
<?php
namespace Ng\AddAttribute\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory) {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY, 'disposizione', [
            'type'     => 'int',
            'label'    => 'Disposizione',
            'input'    => 'boolean',
            'source'   => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Boolean',
            'visible'  => true,
            'default'  => '0',
            'required' => false,
            'global'   => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
            'group'    => 'Display Settings',
        ]);
    }
}
```

To have it run again, you need to remove that module's row from the setup_module table with a query like below:

```
DELETE FROM `setup_module` WHERE `module` LIKE ('%Ng_AddAttribute%');
```

After that run setup:upgrade command.

Answer (score 0):

File : app/code/Namespace/Modulename/Setup/Patch/Data/AddMultiBrandCatAttribute.php

```php
    <?php
    /**
     * Copyright © Category All rights reserved.
     * See COPYING.txt for license details.
     */
    declare(strict_types=1);

    namespace Namespace/Modulename\Setup\Patch\Data;

    use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface;
    use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
    use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
    use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\DataPatchInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\PatchRevertableInterface;

    class AddMultiBrandCatAttribute implements DataPatchInterface, PatchRevertableInterface
    {

        /**
         * @var ModuleDataSetupInterface
         */
        private $moduleDataSetup;
        /**
         * @var EavSetupFactory
         */
        private $eavSetupFactory;

        /**
         * Constructor
         *
         * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup
         * @param EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
         */
        public function __construct(
            ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup,
            EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
        ) {
            $this->moduleDataSetup = $moduleDataSetup;
            $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
        }

        /**
         * {@inheritdoc}
         */
        public function apply()
        {
            $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->startSetup();
            /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
            $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $this->moduleDataSetup]);
            $eavSetup->addAttribute(
                \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY,
                'multi_brands',
                [
                    'type' => 'int',
                    'label' => 'Multi Brands',
                    'input' => 'select',
                    'sort_order' => 333,
                    'source' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Boolean',
                    'global' => ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                    'visible' => true,
                    'required' => false,
                    'user_defined' => false,
                    'default' => 0,
                    'group' => 'General Information',
                    'backend' => ''
                ]
            );

            $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->endSetup();
        }

        public function revert()
        {
            $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->startSetup();
            /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
            $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $this->moduleDataSetup]);
            $eavSetup->removeAttribute(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY, 'multi_brands');

            $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->endSetup();
        }

        /**
         * {@inheritdoc}
         */
        public function getAliases()
        {
            return [];
        }

        /**
         * {@inheritdoc}
         */
        public static function getDependencies()
        {
            return [

            ];
        }
    }
```

File : view/adminhtml/ui_component/category_form.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
     <fieldset name="general">
        <field name="multi_brands">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">50</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">boolean</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">checkbox</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Multi Source</item>
                    <item name="prefer" xsi:type="string">toggle</item>
                    <item name="valueMap" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="true" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                        <item name="false" xsi:type="string">0</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="default" xsi:type="number">0</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>

    </fieldset>

</form>
```

Run : php -dmemory_limit=6G bin/magento setup:upgrade

This will solve your problem, Hope that helps